# Installing pg_profile for postgreSql

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to use the extension pg_profile in order to get awr-like reports in postgreSql.
In githab README file it says:
https://github.com/zubkov-andrei/pg_profile

```
# cp pg_profile* `pg_config --sharedir`/extension
```

and then:

```
postgres=# CREATE EXTENSION pg_profile;
```

But this fails with:

```
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/11/extension/pg_profile.control": No such file or directory
```

and indeed I can only find pg_profile.control.tpl in under this directory (and in the zip file I downloaded from Github).

IF I try to follow the tutorial instructions saying:

https://dbtut.com/index.php/2019/03/29/postgresql-awr/

> After downloading the file to the server, go the directory you
> downloaded and follow the steps below. We’re running the Make command.
> make install

Then I get this error:

```
# make install
Makefile:16: ../../src/Makefile.global: No such file or directory
Makefile:17: /contrib/contrib-global.mk: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target '/contrib/contrib-global.mk'.  Stop.
```

Any idea how to solve these?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to run CREATE EXTENSION in PG 12.3 database but to do that:

- I have removed the line  `PG_CONFIG = /usr/local/pgsql/bin/pg_config` in `Makefile`:
- I have run as root:

  ```
  $ make USE_PGXS=y install
        /usr/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/pgsql-12/share/extension'
        /usr/bin/mkdir -p '/usr/pgsql-12/share/extension'
        /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 .//pg_profile.control '/usr/pgsql-12/share/extension/'
        /usr/bin/install -c -m 644  pg_profile--0.1.1.sql pg_profile.control '/usr/pgsql-12/share/extension/'
  ```

And after that I could run without error:

```
postgres=# CREATE EXTENSION dblink;
postgres=# CREATE EXTENSION pg_stat_statements;
postgres=# CREATE EXTENSION pg_profile;

postgres=# \dx
                                       List of installed extensions
        Name        | Version |   Schema   |                         Description                          
--------------------+---------+------------+--------------------------------------------------------------
 dblink             | 1.2     | public     | connect to other PostgreSQL databases from within a database
 pg_profile         | 0.1.1   | public     | PostgreSQL load profile repository and report builder
 pg_stat_statements | 1.7     | public     | track execution statistics of all SQL statements executed
 plpgsql            | 1.0     | pg_catalog | PL/pgSQL procedural language
 postgres_fdw       | 1.0     | public     | foreign-data wrapper for remote PostgreSQL servers
(5 rows)
```

Comment: Removing the line from the Makefile did allow the pg_profile.control to be created in the extension directory!  however the CREATE EXTNESION fails... Maybe it is not suitable for PG 11: ` # CREATE EXTENSION pg_profile;
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "
INE 1: CREATE EXTENSION pg_profile;`

Comment: well, the installation documentation is not very clear and if you really want to work with this extension I suggest you create an issue on https://github.com/zubkov-andrei/pg_profile/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aclosed.

Comment: Thank you Pifor.. will try this